# Setting default value of Mysql Columns using PHP Input Box Value

Tags: php, mysql

I am very new to PHP and MySql. Is there any method by which using PHP script taking value through input box can we set the default value of the column using an update query with this value, rather than alter table function?

**Update 1:**

I want whatever value I send through my form to become default value of that column. There will be some other columns, whose values should change and not set as default, while other default values should appear in the input box for further updating.

For example, there are 3 columns: `A`, `B`, `C`.  Column `A` has `currdate` value. Columns B and C are some integer values. Say a user opens the form, he sees the currdate is `02-07-2012` for the column A. Then he enters some values: B = 5, C = 6. The next day when the user opens the form, the currdate will become 03-07-2012. Simultaneously the value of `B` and `C` will automatically change from `null` to 5 and 6, with previous row value the same as default value.

So is it possible that every new row takes the previous value entered from the form as the default value of the column set in the mysql table?

Comment: @khaled_webdev thanx dear as its not a empty column i just want whatever i update through my form submission using update query the last subbmitted value should became default column value for that column so that if other rows increased these calum automatically have taken the previous value for more precise i want to make defult values of a colum to be dynamic and can be updated through PHP form using update query rather than alter table query

Comment: do a select * from table order by id (or date) desc limit 1 , and fill input value with the results

Comment: @khaled_webdev sorry dear but its not working. i tried it but end result is same.

Comment: show us some code (php, html)

Comment: @khaled_webdev ok i will add my codes try to find the most small form so it will be easy to understand

Comment: @khaled_webdev i have added the codes please check

Comment: sorry, im buzzy but i will check it when i got time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understood You have input fields which update MySQL table. And You have some information in database which will be updated. And fields which are not filled, are not updated in mysql, so it does not empty rows? If that, You could get data from database, then after submitting a form, check whether field is empty and if field is empty, add to that field value which was got from database.

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = 1";
$result = $dbh->query($sql);
$data = $result->fetch_assoc();
?>
<form action="#" method="post" id="form">
<input type="text" id="name" class="aa"/>
<input type="text" id="email" class="aa"/>
<input type="button" id="subm" value="Update" />
</form>
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#subm").click(function () {
        $(".aa").each(function () {
            var value = $(this).val();
            if (value == "") {
                var id = $(this).attr("id");
                $("#"+id).attr("value", "<?=$data['"+id+"']?>");
            }
        });
        $("#form").submit();
    });
});
</script>
```

I dont remember how I could go through each input, so I added class, which is not good. Search in google - each loop for input field jquery.

Comment: hey Daniels Pitkevičs thanx for your reply really appriciated

Comment: thanx dear but i have updated my question again i think i was unable to define it correctly and here in comment box i am unable to have it compaletely please chek it again i think i m looking for somthing else